# Menu prints twice and default runs even when case doesn't match

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, case

I am trying to show the user a menu and allow them to pick from the options. It's in a while loop because it has to iterate until option "e" is picked to exit the program. I included the "default" option as a fail-safe for if the user inputs a value that is not accepted. The default case always runs no matter what I do and the menu always appears twice after the initial run of the code.
I have tried changing "getchar()" to the scanf and it still produces the same duplicated output. I have also tried doing away with the switch entirely, but I get the same result using if/then statements. I have attached my full code and any help is appreciated thank you!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    // function for the menu
   char menu() {
printf("Please select from the following menu: \n");
// setting up the menu from here
printf("a. input the data files location \n");
printf("b. enter the time interval \n");
printf("c. process and display the US Life Expectancy Data \n");
printf("d. process and display the Statistics of All Data \n");
printf("e. exit the program \n");
    }

    char options(char choice) {
switch (choice) {
case 'a':
    printf("choice a\n");
    break;
case 'b':
    printf("choice b\n");
    break;
case 'c':
    printf("choice c\n");
    break;
case 'd':
    printf("choice d\n");
    break;
case 'e':
    break;
default: // default when none of the cases are matched
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    break;
}
    }

    // main function
    int main(void) {
char choice;
do {
    menu();
    while ((choice = getchar()) == "\n") {};
    if (choice == EOF) {
        exit(1);
    }
    options(choice);
} while (choice != 'e');
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you get some compiler warnings? You should turn them to maximum.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char`. You should not use a global variable `choice`. Especially as you pass the variable to `option`.

Comment: You don't have a `while` loop but a `do while` loop. Some hint for debugging: Whenever you enter the `default` case, print the value. Use `%d`, not `%c` for that. You might find an extra `13` for each input.

Comment: Could you also fix the signature of the function options() that should take a parameter, and activate a higher level of warnings (-Wall)

Comment: You have non-void functions that do not return anything. And empty parameter lists but provide parameters. I suggest to revisit the chapter about functions in your learning material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code doesn't handle newlines. In other words when you type `a` followed by ENTER, your code actually receives two characters. The `'a'` and a `'\n'`. Therefore the menu will be printed twice and you get an "invalid input".

A quick fix could be:

```
choice = getchar(); --> while ((choice = getchar()) == '\n') {};
```

That said, you should change `choice` to be an `int` and also do:

```
int choice;

....
....

    while ((choice = getchar()) == '\n') {};
    if (choice == EOF)
    {
        // Fatal input error
        exit(1);
    }
```

Finally, it's a bad idea to have `choice` as a global. Instead put it in `main` and pass it as an argument to the function `options`. But don't pass it to `menu`. So do:

```
char options() { --> char options(int choice) {
```

and

```
int main(void) {
    int choice;
    do {
        menu();
        while ((choice = getchar()) == '\n') {};  // ignore newlines
        if (choice == EOF)
        {
            // Fatal input error
            exit(1);
        }
        options(choice);
    } while (choice != 'e');
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful in giving me the scope to understand what mistakes I was making; however, I am still having the same problem I was before with the menu printing twice and running the default case. I will edit my question with the updated code.

Comment: @triniti Look *very carefully* at the line you typed, and compare it to the `while ((choice = getchar()) == '\n') {};` line that 4386427 typed.  (I didn't spot the error, either, but my compiler did.)

Comment: @triniti Your edited code is not the same a mine. Most important you have written `"\n"` where I do `'\n'` That's an important difference! Also you have `char choice;` and I have `int choice;`

Comment: Thank you!! My code runs perfectly now thank you so much for the help!!!